# What should be the input array shape for training models with Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I was following tutorial steps for training a neural network with Tensorflow as given on https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit

while running the fitting function on the training data ValueError with problem with the input shape was encountered.

Model architechture:

```
NUM_WORDS = 10000
baseline_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu',input_shape(NUM_WORDS,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])

baseline_model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                       loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                       metrics=['accuracy', 'binary_crossentropy'])
baseline_model.summary()
```

[image]

```
baseline_history = baseline_model.fit(train_data, 
                                      train_labels, 
                                      epochs=20, 
                                      batch_size=512, 
                                      validation_data=(test_data, test_labels), 
                                      verbose=2)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 4                                       batch_size=512,
> 5                                       validation_data=(test_data, test_labels),
> ----> 6                                       verbose=2)
>
> ~/env_tensorflow2_alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing,
> **kwargs)
> 816           batch_size=batch_size,
> 817           steps=validation_steps,
> --> 818           steps_name='validation_steps')
> 819     elif validation_split and 0. < validation_split < 1.:
> 820       if training_utils.has_symbolic_tensors(x):
>
> ~/env_tensorflow2_alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight,
> batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split, shuffle,
> extract_tensors_from_dataset)    2594           feed_input_shapes,
> 2595           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch
> size.
> -> 2596           exception_prefix='input')    2597     2598     if y is not None:
>
> ~/env_tensorflow2_alpha/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
> exception_prefix)
> 347                              ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
> 348                              str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
> --> 349                              str(data_shape))
> 350   return data
> 351
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_21_input to have
> shape (10000,) but got array with shape (1,)

train_data and train_labels have the following shape:

```
print("Train data shape: ", train_data.shape)
print("Train label shape: ", train_labels.shape)
```

> Train data shape:  (25000, 10000)
> Train label shape: (25000,)

Why am I getting an error here, and do I need to accommodate another dimension for the batch_size in the input array?

I am working with Tensorflow version: 2.0.0-alpha0

Answer (score 1):

The code looks perfectly fine to me except for a small bug in the line,

`keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu',input_shape(NUM_WORDS,))`

where you missed a `=` so it should have been,

`keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu',input_shape=(NUM_WORDS,))`

I was able to run the same code in google colab space with no error.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a small bug, when you are providing input shape it should be like

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
```

And most of the cases you can just leave the input argument to be empty and it will still work fine.